# How to remove footer credits from "Blog Diary by Theme Palace" Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, footer, credits

I understand that theme designers shall be credited for their creation but sometimes we need a site that will look more professional and we can't afford to pay for the credit removal so what we can do here is to just remove the theme credits from the source code itself.

**Is it legal?**

I have no idea and I think that it depends on the license that the theme goes under but for what  I am sure is that this precise theme allows you to remove their credit from the theme footer if you know how to do it ([you can find that information here](https://themepalace.com/topic/editing-the-footer/)) so that is why in this post I want to show you how to actually remove the footer credits from the "Blog Diary by Theme Palace" theme.

**The Simple Solution**

First, you need to go to your WordPress Dashboard and find **Appearance>>Theme Editor**.

Then, on the right side of the editor, you will find the **Theme Files** and go at **inc>>structure.php**

Then make sure to click somewhere in the code editing area and when you see your mouse cursor blinking, press **CTRL+F** on your keyboard and wait for a search bar to show up at the top of the coding area *(if you don't click the coding area, the search box will appear in the top-right corner of the web browser and will show no results after executing the next step)*

The next step is to paste **$poweredby_text** in the search box and hit enter

And lastly, you put two slashes **(//)** before the **$poweredby_text** so the code can look like this:

```
//$poweredby_text = esc_html( $theme_data->get( 'Name') ) . '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'by', 'blog-diary' ). '&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="'. esc_url( $theme_data->get( 'AuthorURI' ) ) .'">'. esc_html( ucwords( $theme_data->get( 'Author' ) ) ) .'</a>';
```

This line of code has a function to display the theme credits in the footer and it is written in such a complicated way so you can't find it easily, it is also placed in a hidden location that makes it a bit harder to find.

What this does to the code is that it turns the entire line of the code into a comment and since comments serve only as a form of note they don't allow the code to execute it's function and display the copyright claim in the footer.

I am aware that this is not a question and belongs to the wiki part but I haven't used this site in a while and I don't remember how I'm supposed to include it to the wiki section so here it goes as a question.

Comment: You need 10 rep to create wiki posts

Comment: If you meant this to be a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it needs to be split into two posts and both must meet the usual quality criteria. I'm not sure what you mean by *"wiki section"*; I don't know what [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) this would fit into and [community wiki posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) also need to be good posts.